# need help on ajax with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

i am creating a registration page with email id and password . i have called onsubmit event in registration page which call's checkData() function which is written in a common.js file. i have a ajax function to check whether email id exist in database or not ? but my problem is when i keep alert message after the completion of checking my ajax function works fine but if alert is removed it enter's data in to database. here is the code of ajax

```
   else
   {
       $(function() {

              $.ajax({
                    url  : 'RegCheck.php',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : 'User=' + address,
                    success : function(result){
                       if(result != "No")
                       {
                           document.getElementById("EmailChk").innerHTML = result;    
                           Valid = false;

                       }
                    }

              });              


       });                         
      document.getElementById("MailMand").innerHTML = "" ;

   }    
   alert(Valid);
   return Valid;
```

Comment: Needed to see inside your `RegCheck.php` file and how you using `Valid = false;` functionality ...

Comment: RegCheck.php is <?php
 require("Connect.php");
 $Data = $_POST['User'];
 $Qry = "select UserName from UserMst where UserName = '$Data' ";
 $Result = mysql_query($Qry) or die("User Check Failed");
 $Final = mysql_numrows($Result);
 if($Final > 0)
 {
     echo " Already Registered"  ;
 }
 else
 {
     echo "No";
 }
?>

Answer (score 1):

ajax doesn't work that way.  The `success` code will execute *after* the `return Valid` code 99.9% of the time (if not 100% of the time).  You ***can't guarantee*** when the `success` will be called.

Instead, you need to do all of your work in the `ajax` callback or (*shudder*) make it synchronous.

So if you're depending on it for validation, you need to stop the form from submitting and then submit the form in the `success` method.

Comment: but when i put an alert message after the completion of ajax my result shows as already registed email but if i remove the alert message it fire's my insert query